# How can I shorten controller methods that is called by Route Class? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a journal like site. It has lots of Models: `Post`, `User`, `UserJournal`, `Comment` as well as `Journal`. To render Journals I use `getJournal` method of `Journal` class. Because `getJournal` method calls methods from all Models, it is soo long.

I have read that methods should be as short as possible. Laravel methods, for example, are really short. How can I shorten my methods called from Route class?

One possible solution I come up is to increase the size of `__construct` method of `Journal` class. So that I will gather all information here;
`$posts` of the journal, `$userjournals` of the user, etc.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Without checking the actual code we can't suggest much.

Comment: @Sandeesh is correct, please share some of the code, what is in the `getJournal` method?